# Disabling OpenMP in compiler options produce tons of reference errors

Tags: c, openmp, icc

I have a project in C and I need to measure program performance in parallel and sequential mode.

Program is parallelized with openmp.

If I compile my program with -openmp flag everything is fine.

But if I replace -openmp with -openmp-stubs I get tons of reference errors:

```
ccc.c:614: undefined reference to `__kmpc_for_static_init_4'
ccc.c:614: undefined reference to `__kmpc_for_static_fini'
ccc.c:624: undefined reference to `__kmpc_barrier'
build/liblcthw.a(ccc.o): In function `deusv2v_dbg':
ccc.c:632: undefined reference to `__kmpc_global_thread_num'
ccc.c:632: undefined reference to `__kmpc_ok_to_fork'
ccc.c:632: undefined reference to `__kmpc_fork_call'
ccc.c:632: undefined reference to `__kmpc_serialized_parallel'
ccc.c:632: undefined reference to `__kmpc_end_serialized_parallel'
build/liblcthw.a(ccc.o): In function `L_deusv2v_dbg_632__par_region0_2_862':
ccc.c:636: undefined reference to `__kmpc_for_static_init_4'
ccc.c:636: undefined reference to `__kmpc_for_static_fini'
ccc.c:646: undefined reference to `__kmpc_barrier'
build/liblcthw.a(ccc.o): In function `seusv2v_dbg':
ccc.c:654: undefined reference to `__kmpc_global_thread_num'
ccc.c:654: undefined reference to `__kmpc_ok_to_fork'
ccc.c:654: undefined reference to `__kmpc_fork_call'
ccc.c:654: undefined reference to `__kmpc_serialized_parallel'
ccc.c:654: undefined reference to `__kmpc_end_serialized_parallel'
build/liblcthw.a(ccc.o): In function `L_seusv2v_dbg_654__par_region0_2_954':
ccc.c:658: undefined reference to `__kmpc_for_static_init_4'
ccc.c:658: undefined reference to `__kmpc_for_static_fini'
ccc.c:668: undefined reference to `__kmpc_barrier'
```

Compiler: icc version 13.1.3 (gcc version 4.4.6 compatibility)

What I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to temporary disable openmp in other way?

I use omp_get_wtime to measure performance time so I can't just disable OpenMP at all.

Comment: How about `set OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`?

Comment: In my earlier experiments it gives very different performance.

Comment: Did you do a proper cleaning before to re-compile? It looks to me like the `build/liblcthw.a` survived the cleaning...

Comment: If you had actually linked against openmp stubs library you wouldn't be seeing those missing references.  As hinted above, differences between 1 thread and stubs library performance are unlikely.